# VS Code: There is no attributes for site-packges modules in python?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, wxpython

Guys when I installed wxpython by this `pip install wxpython` when I back to import wx in python file in VS Code there is no options menu for the module oppsite of already installed modules come with python like :
[image]

but when I want to show this menu in wxpython i don't have it?? :
[image]

Help me
any Help will be in the heart ♥

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VSCode, the prompt function of automatic completion is provided by the Python extension and language service, and the content of the code prompt is different when using different language services. The following is the situation when I use three different Python language services:

1. `"python.languageServer":"Pylance",` (in "settings.json" file)

   [image]
2. `"python.languageServer":"Microsoft",`

   [image]
3. `"python.languageServer":"Jedi",`

   [image]

It is recommended that you try to reload VSCode (`F1`, `Developer: Reload Window`) and wait for the python language service to load, then type the code to use the code hint function to get a better use effect.